# Upload file from android to PHP server using retrofit

Tags: php, android, kotlin, file-upload, retrofit2

I have some problem with uploading image into PHP server. In this case, first I'l get image from gallery than create the output as base64, then I convert base64 to file using stream, then upload it into server. Here is my code.

UploadActivity.kt

```
private fun updatePhoto(variable: String, file: Bitmap, userId: String) {
    val encode = encodedImage(file)

    val outputDir: File = this.cacheDir
    val f = File.createTempFile(userId, ".jpeg", outputDir)

    var fos: FileOutputStream? = null
    try {
        fos = FileOutputStream(f)
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    try {
        fos!!.write(encode)
        fos.flush()
        fos.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    val builder = MultipartBody.Builder()
    builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM)

    val requestFile = f.asRequestBody(getMimeType(f.path)?.toMediaTypeOrNull())

    builder.addFormDataPart(variable, f.name, requestFile)
    builder.addFormDataPart("userId", userId)

    val apiService = ApiInterface.create()
    val call = apiService.updatePicture(builder.build())

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<UserModel> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<UserModel>,
            response: retrofit2.Response<UserModel>?
        ) {
            val jsonObject = response!!.body()
            val returnedResponse = jsonObject!!.status
            if (returnedResponse!!.trim { it <= ' ' } == "200") {
                val intent = Intent(this@UploadPreviewActivity, ProfileActivity::class.java)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@UploadPreviewActivity,
                    "Terjadi kesalahan, harap coba kembali.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserModel>, t: Throwable) {
            call.cancel()
            Toast.makeText(
                this@UploadPreviewActivity,
                "Harap periksa koneksi internet anda",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
    })
}
```

Interface.kt

```
@POST("user-update-picture")
fun updatePicture(@Body requestBody: RequestBody): Call<UserModel>
```

Upload.php

```
function resize_image($file) {
    $src = imagecreatefromstring($file);
    if (!$src) return false;
    $width = imagesx($src);
    $height = imagesy($src);
    
    $newwidth = $width*0.5;
    $newheight = $height*0.5;
    
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
    
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg($dst);
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $data;
}

function decodeImage($picturePath, $dir, $dir_thumb, $userId){
    $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', str_replace('[removed]', '', $picturePath));
    $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
    $data  = base64_decode($image);
    $data2  = base64_decode($picturePath);
    
    $thumb = $this->resize_image($data2);
    
    $file = './files/images/'.$dir.'/'.$userId.'.jpg';
    $upload = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    
    $file2 = './files/images/'.$dir_thumb.'/'.$userId.'.jpg';
    $upload2 = file_put_contents($file2, $thumb);
}

public function picture_post(){
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    $Date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    
    $userId = filter_var($this->post('userId'), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    
    if (isset($_FILES['userPhotoPath']['tmp_name']) && !empty($_FILES['userPhotoPath']['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['userPhotoPath']['tmp_name']!=NULL) {
        $photoPath = $_FILES['userPhotoPath']['tmp_name'];
        $photoType = $_FILES['userPhotoPath']['type'];
        $photoData = file_get_contents($photoPath);
        $userPhotoPath = 'data:' . $photoType . ';base64,' . base64_encode($photoData);
        if(file_exists("./files/images/users/".$userId.".jpg")){
            $unlink = unlink("./files/images/users/".$userId.".jpg");
        }
        if(file_exists("./files/images/users_thumb/".$userId.".jpg")){
            $unlink2 = unlink("./files/images/users_thumb/".$userId.".jpg");
        }
        $this->decodeImage($userPhotoPath, 'users', 'users_thumb', $userId);
    }else{
        $userPhotoPath = NULL;
    }
}
```

Then when I upload the file from android I get this error in Okhttp Log

> Message:  imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format
> Backtrace:
> Function: imagecreatefromstring

I don't know why, because my PHP code work with my web version of this application with same upload method using javascript

Comment: why do you covert it as basesix4 ? just write file in your local directory and pass the path to retrofit

Comment: I do edit image like rotate and etc manually by user before upload it @Manikandan

Comment: so what..we could able to save edited image in local directory ..and send path to server.

Comment: Yes I do that but still getting error from server return.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by my self and this my mistake,
I change this code

```
function decodeImage($picturePath, $dir, $dir_thumb, $userId){
   $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', str_replace('[removed]', '', $picturePath));
   $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
   $data  = base64_decode($image);
   $data2  = base64_decode($picturePath);

   $thumb = $this->resize_image($data2);

   $file = './files/images/'.$dir.'/'.$userId.'.jpg';
   $upload = file_put_contents($file, $data);

   $file2 = './files/images/'.$dir_thumb.'/'.$userId.'.jpg';
   $upload2 = file_put_contents($file2, $thumb);
}
```

into this

```
function decodeImage($picturePath, $dir, $dir_thumb, $userId){
   $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', str_replace('[removed]', '', $picturePath));
   $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
   $data  = base64_decode($image);

   $thumb = $this->resize_image($data);

   $file = './files/images/'.$dir.'/'.$userId.'.jpg';
   $upload = file_put_contents($file, $data);

   $file2 = './files/images/'.$dir_thumb.'/'.$userId.'.jpg';
   $upload2 = file_put_contents($file2, $thumb);
}
```

This is my little mistake I forgot about the rezise_image content requirement, after change that code this upload work 100% without any problem again.